# Is $f'(a)$ Not same as Finding Derivative of $f(x)$ and Substituting $x=a$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, limits, derivatives, continuity

I got this doubt regarding the differentiability of function $f(x)$ at $x=0$ where

$$f(x)= \begin{cases}
            x^2 \sin\left(\frac 1 x\right) & x \ne 0\\
            0 & x=0
         \end{cases}
$$

We know that $f(x)$ is Differentiable at $x=0$ and the Slope of tangent at $x=0$ is Zero Since RHD = LHD

But i am getting confused of the notation many books use for RHD = LHD = $f'(a)$

Because $f'(a)$ is value of the function's Derivative at $x=a$ in this case we have

$$f'(x)=-\cos \left(\frac{1}{x}\right)+2x \sin\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)$$ So $f'(0)$ Does not exist. But since $f(x)$ is differentiable at $x=0$ the notation says $f'(0)=0$

So i need clarification in this ?

Comment: You wrote "So $f'(0)$ does not exist. But the expression you wrote after $f'(x)={}$ is valid only when $x\ne0.$ So you can't draw a conclusion from that about whether $f'(0)$ exists. $\qquad$

Answer (score 13, accepted):

When you found the expression for $f'(x)$, the expression you used for $f(x)$ isn't valid for $x = 0$. Therefore there is no reason to expect the expression you find for $f'(x)$ to be valid for $x = 0$ either.

For $x = 0$, it's better to turn to the definition:
$$
f'(0) = \lim_{h\to 0}\,\frac{f(h) - f(0)}{h}\\
= \lim_{h\to 0}\,\frac{h^2\sin(1/h)}{h}\\
= \lim_{h\to 0}\,h\sin(1/h) = 0
$$
Here is a graph of the function $f$, close to the origin:

[image]

You can see how each wave oscillates wildly (I've stretched the $y$-axis some, so it's exaggerated), but as a whole the graph flattens out, as it's squeezed between the two parabolas $y = x^2$ and $y = -x^2$. This is the reason it can be differentiable at $0$ even though the expression for $f'(x)$ doesn't make sense or even has a limit as $x\to 0$.

As a second way to look at this, if I *hadn't* stretched out the $y$-axis in the graph above, all we would have seen would be a somewhat thick line along the $x$-axis. Which means that close to the origin, the line $y = 0$ is actually a good approximation to $f(x)$, close to $x = 0$. The existence of a line which is a good approximation, under a certain strictly defined sense of "good approximation" (basically, no matter how much I stretch the $y$-axis to make the approximation look bad, just zooming in will eventually make it look good again), is the *definition* of differentiable, and a notion which is readily generalized to higher dimensions.

This function is the standard example illustrating the difference between a a function being differentiable and a function being *continuously* differentiable.

Comment: Thanks so you mean to say the expression $f'(x)=0$ when $x=0$ even after finding derivative, but only limits do not exist?

Comment: @Miguel No, $f'(x)$ is discontinuous at the origin. See, for instance, [this plot](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+d%2Fdx+x%5E2*sin(1%2Fx)) (which isn't a proof, I know; a real proof can be done by showing that $\lim_{x\to 0}f'(x)$ doesn't exist, even though $f'(0)$ does). It is true that if a function is differentiable, then its derivative cannot have jump discontinuities. But that's not what's happening here.

Comment: @Arthur My wrong :(

Comment: Cool... $(+1)$ ${}$

Comment: @Arthur is that plot shown by you is $x^2 \sin\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)$ because this is odd function right?

Comment: @Umeshshankar Yes, that is $x^2\sin(1/x)$, and it _is_ an odd function. It's just a bit difficult to distinguish even from odd when the oscillations are so dense. You can look at the signs of $f(\pm0.01)$ (I think $f(-0.01)$ looks positive and $f(0.01)$ looks negative) to see that it at least _seems_ odd. Don't look at the rightmost and leftmost cut, as I haven't done those evenly.

Comment: yes correct i got it after zooming  it really looks like even function